# make results unique by using group by condition

Tags: php, mysql, join, group-by, distinct

Here i want to join two table and want to produce the output like

```
Akbar Travels building      2018-10
Thrikandiyur Quarters       2018-10


Akbar Travels building     2018-11
Thrikandiyur Quarters      2018-11
```

Here i have two tables name `table A,table B`,`table A` structure looks like this

```
 category_id           category_name    
    5               Akbar Travels building          
    6               Thrikandiyur Quarters
```

`table B` structure looks like this

```
id   paying_date   paying_month     parent_category     
1    2018-10-01      2018-10            5   
2    2018-10-01      2018-10            5   
3    2018-10-01      2018-11            5   
4    2018-11-01      2018-11            5   
5    2018-10-01      2018-10            6
6    2018-10-10      2018-12            5
```

Here for getting output i wrote my code code like this

```
public function get_date_wise_pdf_report($from, $to)
{
       $query=$this->db->query("SELECT distinct A.category_name,B.paying_month from tableA A left join tableB B  on A.category_id = B.parent_category and B.paying_date BETWEEN '{$from}' AND '{$to}' order by B.paying_month");
       return $query->result();
 }
```

but when i use this am getting like this

```
Akbar Travels building     2018-10
Thrikandiyur Quarters      2018-10
Akbar Travels building     2018-10
Thrikandiyur Quarters      2018-10
```

Am unable to give group by statement here and if i gave only two rows will be the out come,please help me to solve

Comment: You have no data in `table B` for `Thrikandiyur Quarters` in `2018-11` so I'm not sure how you expect to get your expected result?

Comment: Try this query : "SELECT distinct A.category_name,B.paying_month from tableA A left join tableB B  on A.category_id = B.parent_category WHERE B.paying_date BETWEEN '{$from}' AND '{$to}' order by B.paying_month"

Comment: @Nick i can get that resultby using UNION if i get what is present for  `table B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using subquery

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=9117e5e285e2e38a59cc04d186bcabff)

```
 select distinct catname,paymon
from
(SELECT A.catname,DATE_FORMAT(B.paydate, "%Y-%m") as paymon from  A 
left join  B  on A.catid = B.parentcatid and B.paydate BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-12-31'
)X order by paymon
```

Comment: i got the result like this first row is  `Akbar Travels building`  `2018-10` and second row is  `Thrikandiyur Quarters`  `2018-10` third row is `Akbar Travels building`  `2018-11` and fourth row is `Akbar Travels building`  `2018-12`

Comment: @user_777 what is your expected output?

Comment: here its correct if we take paying_month as the distinct value but i want to take paying_date value as the distinct value

Comment: @user_77, you want to paying date as date or month?

Comment: @user_77, I didn't get your point - bettwe if you provide your expected output with sample data - otherwie answering based on guess in tough

Comment: here `2018-10` is the value taken from the `paying_date' that means the value of month and year is taking from `paying_date`

Comment: i want my output to be look like this `Akbar Travels building`      `2018-10`
`Thrikandiyur Quarters`       `2018-10` if i choose the date between `2018-10-01` and `2018-10-31` and if i choose the date between `2018-10-01` and `2018-11-31`  i want my result to be like  `Akbar Travels building`      `2018-10`
`Thrikandiyur Quarters`       `2018-10`
`Akbar Travels building`     `2018-11`

Comment: @user_777, you can check here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=58eeea6a16b1457daac197e121475c49

Comment: in your solution  the paymonth should be the value taken from the `paying_date` not from the `pay_month`

Comment: @user_777, modified the answer - you can check now